# how to filter each tag item?

Tags: tags, terms

By default wordpress displays tags as:

`Tagged in: Tag1, Tag2, Tag3`, ...so on

I want to print it as

`Tagged in: #Tag1, #Tag2, #Tag3, ...so on`

I know I can do this using CSS by using `:before`, but I thought of doing this the PHP way. I searched the documentation and couldn't figure out much, any help regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

On the top of my head there are two easy ways to go about this problem, first is to use the `get_the_tags()` function to manually loop the tags to easily insert the hashtags.

```
$tags = get_the_tags();

if ( $tags ) {
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->id ); ?>">
            <?php echo '#' . $tag->name . ', '; ?>
        </a>

    <?php
    }
}
```

Another way to do it, but will give you less customisation options is straight up using the `the_tags()` function. Here is an example.

`the_tags( 'Tagged in: #', ', #' );`

The first parameter is what will show before the loop starts, so here you will need to insert the first `#`, the second parameter is what will loop after every tag is being output.

You can read up on the functions here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

Hope this helped and good luck!